# How to demonstrate that a class isn't thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading

I am kinda new to threads. How can I prove, by writing code in a separate class, that *MyClass* class isn't thread safe? I've been searching but I can't really find an example to aid me.

```
public class MyClass {
  private static int value = 0;
  
  public static void set(int setVal) {
    value = setVal;
  }

  public static int get() {
    return value;
  }  

  public static void decrement() {
    int temp = value;
    value = --temp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Re, "I can't really find an example to aid me." That's because testing for thread safety is unreliable. Many different things could happen when you run a thread _unsafe_ program. Some of them are bad. Some of them are not. The behavior of an unsafe program could change when you run it on a different machine, when you run it under a different OS, when you run it under a different update of the same OS, when you run it on a different day, when you run it at the same time as different other programs, when you compile it with a different compiler, etc.

Comment: Oh okay. Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: Maybe it is Mrs. IntoVoid? Or something in between.

Comment: Holy crap you're right. Apologies for assuming D:

Comment: You don't demonstrate it with code. You sho, analytically, that a class *is* threadsafe, because it uses `synchronized` or semaphores correctly, or, which is much harder, has all the right happens-before relationships: and if you can't prove that, or haven't tried, it isn't thread-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int nt = 10;
    int c = 20000;

    MyClass.set(c);

    Thread[] threads = new Thread[nt];

    for (int t = 0; t < nt; t++) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < c; i += nt) {
                MyClass.decrement();
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        threads[t] = thread;
    }

    try {
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }
    } catch (Throwable tr) {
        tr.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(MyClass.get());
}
```

Try this. If you add synchronized to the decrement method of MyClass it will print out 0 (thread safe), but if you don't synchronize decrement than it will print out a wrong number.

This proves that MyClass (its decrement method) is not thread prove, since if it was it would print out 0.

Also, if you can't use lambdas than replace the first for loop with the following:

```
for (int t = 0; t < nt; t++) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i += nt) {
            MyClass.decrement();
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    threads[t] = thread;
}
```

Hope I could help!

Comment: Yeah it did, thanks Mr. IntoVoid! Now I'm off to understand it.